# for loop not running, trying to iterate backwards through array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop

To practice using pointers and arrays i'm trying to do a simple program capable of converting a binary input to denary.. i think i have a good idea for the logic but i haven't even got round to trying to implement it because im struggling to get my *for* loop running!

It seems silly but i know the code inside the for loop works fine outside of it, **so it must be something wrong with the condition..? im trying to start at the back of the char array (navigating using pointers) and output each char(as an int) up to the first element.**

So the desired output is "0 - 1 - 0 - 1 -"

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

//prototypes
void binaryToDenary(const char* input, int& inputLength);

int main(){

    const char binaryInput[] = {1,0,1,0};
    int inputLength = sizeof(binaryInput)/sizeof(binaryInput[0]);

    binaryToDenary(binaryInput, inputLength);

    return 0;
}
void binaryToDenary(const char* input, int& inputLength){
    //testing some stuff--- this all works as expected
    //cout << input[2] << " " << (int)*(input+2) << " " << inputLength <<endl;

    int i;
    for(i = inputLength; i < 0; i--){
        cout << (int)*(input+i) << " - ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you "practice pointers and arrays"? I thought this is tagged C++. That's like preparing for a chess tournament by lifting weights.

Comment: You have a very C-style way of writing in C++, remember that philosophy behind coding is completely different

Comment: several obvious things: 1) `inputLength` should not be passed by reference, as it is not changed in `binaryToDenary()` 2) the for loop accesses no elements (if you replace `i<0` by `i>0` it would access elements 1 to inputLength inclusive, while it should presumably 0 to inputLength-1). 3) in C++ `(int)*(input+i)` is more human readably written as `int(input[i])`.

Comment: Thanks all, talk about a brain malfunction :/ i see all the errors now and feel pretty silly, took on all comments :) i'm just learning so many programming basics and trying to put them all to use at the moment. appreciate everyones patience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop should be this:

```
for(i = inputLength -1 ; i  >= 0; i--)
{
    cout << (int)*(input+i) << " - ";
}
```

There are two problems in your code:

- `i = inputLength` which should be `i = inputLength -1`
- `i < 0` which should be `i >= 0`

---

Also, change the second parameter type from `int &` to `int`:

```
void binaryToDenary(const char* input, int inputLength) //now its better!
```

The type `int&` reduces the use cases, and benefits *almost* nothing. If you use `int &`, then all of these would give *compilation* error:

```
const int inputLength = sizeof(binaryInput)/sizeof(binaryInput[0]);
^^^^ note this

binaryToDenary(binaryInput, inputLength); //compilation error
binaryToDenary(binaryInput, sizeof(binaryInput)/sizeof(binaryInput[0])); //error
binaryToDenary(binaryInput, 4); ////compilation error
```

So use `int`, and all of the above would compile fine!

Answer (score 2):

Array indexes start from zero, so the last element is at `inputLength - 1`. With `i < 0` you exit from the loop immediately as that never be true...

```
for(i = inputLength - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    cout << (int)*(input+i) << " - ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = inputLength; i < 0; i--)
```

will run only if inputLength is less than 0, which is not possible?

You need:

```
for(i = (inputLength-1); i >= 0; i--)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

C arrays are 0 based so a valid index is given by

```
(0 <= i) && (i < array_length)
```

In your program, this means that the position of the last digit in your initialization should be `inputLength - 1` and the loop condition should be `i >= 0`.

(As for why you loop is not running, at the start you have `i == inputLength`, so i is positive, failing the `i < 0` condition immediately).

Answer (score 0):

You want to run as long as `i` is bigger (or maybe equal) to zero. You were trying to run the loop as long as `i` was less than zero, and beginning with a value greater than zero results to that you never enter the loop.

```
for(i = inputLength; i > 0; i--){
        cout << (int)*(input+i) << " - ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check for iteration loop variable `i` to be positive..

However you should use a STL iterator on the binary input vector and not loop on it's content in a c fashion, if you want to practice C++, possible solution could be:

```
vector<char> binaryInput;

binaryInput.push_back(1);
binaryInput.push_back(0);
binaryInput.push_back(1);
binaryInput.push_back(0);

vector<char>::iterator it;

for ( it=myvector.begin() ; it < myvector.end(); it++ ){
    cout << " " << *it << endl; //or whatever you need to do with vector content
}
```